# Service stops when App stop

Tags: android, service

When I close App service stops running,
I have tried START_STICKY but still not working.
I need to show notification whenever server respond

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Receive(), 0, 5000);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Here is my enitre Class
http://justpaste.it/14gqd

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind it with notification. then system allows to run service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
startForeground(999, bindService()/*function to return notification*/);
return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

and this function to return notification.

```
protected Notification bindService(){
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    /*customize notification builder here*/

    return mBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: I only want to show notification when I get respond from server, here is my class https://justpaste.it/14gqd

Comment: system will kill this service as soon as removing app from Recent App list. so set AsyncTask inside service or use IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

Service is Killed As Activity is Destroyed , You might Wanna Look into JobScheduler **or** use TimerTask(Easy to Implements)

Timer Task Example

```
    @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // Perform your long running operations here.

            //Creating new thread for  service
            //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
         timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000); // Executes thetask every 5 seconds.
```

Comment: it also stop when closing App